# Nginx - rewriting in locations

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-location

I want to have 2 differents locations on my nginx server (Ubuntu 16.04). One with my HTML page (**page.com; page.com/sth/sth2**) in **/var/www/html** and one with my PHP API (**page.com/api; page.com/api/v1/test**) in **/var/www/api**. Every request to API should go to the api.php file (I have routing there).

I was trying to do this, and for now page.com/api/api.php is working, but page.com/api/v1/test doesn't (I get 404 Not Found error).

```
root /var/www/html;

location ^~ /api/ {
    root /var/www;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ var/www/api/api.php last;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/api/api.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exchange the /api/ location block with the following:

```
location /api/ {
    root /var/www/api;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /api.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/api.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Then all these requests go to api.php and you can handle the routing there, as you seem to do anyway.

You probably also don't need this part:

```
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Because Nginx does not do anything with .htaccess files anyway - so there is no security risk.

Comment: Okay thanks, but now I get 404 error on both api/api.php and api/v1/test (but there is a /var/www/api/api.php file). Html page /var/www/html/index.html is still working.

Comment: I adjusted my example - the way it is now should work. I suspect SCRIPT_NAME was missing (and it was set before because of your redirect). Also, now it uses the root directory, which makes it easier and more obvious if it needs to be changed.